# Null entity when using .find method in entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have been trying to create a simple portal to track logs from a mobile application. As such, I have used entity framework and MVC3 to help me with this. However recently I have been stuck when trying to retrieve the entity from the database.

Here is the Run class:

```
namespace LifestyleGuide.Models
{
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    [KnownType(typeof(User))]
    public partial class Run
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string User_ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Nullable<int> Distance { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Nullable<int> Duration { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Nullable<int> Calories { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

    }

}
```

User_ID and date are form a composite key where User_ID is a foreign key from the User table.

And the following is the "details" method from the controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(String id, DateTime date)
    {
        using (var db = new inspireEntities())
        {
            Run run = db.Runs.Find(id, date);
            return View(run);
        }
    }
```

However, when i try to run it, the run object always appears as a *null*.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Here are is the view for the homepage.

```
@model IEnumerable<LifestyleGuide.Models.Run>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <center>User ID</center>
        </th>
        <th>
            <center>Date</center>
        </th>
        <th>
            <center>Distance</center>
        </th>
        <th>
            <center>Duration</center>
        </th>
        <th>
            <center>Calories</center>
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User_ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Distance)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Duration)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Calories)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.User_ID, date = item.Date }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.User_ID, date = item.Date }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.User_ID, date = item.Date })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

The fields in the table are populated from the database directly and therefore should already exist.

**Note: I have no problems with creating and accessing the run objects by using the view. The *null* run object only occurs when I directly do an insert statement into the database and when i try to retrieve it afterwards using the .find method as shown above.**

Comment: Since you don't share View or Controller populating View, I wonder: are you certain these keys will always return a record? Do they come from the database already? (optimally chosen together...)

Comment: Thanks for replying! I have edited my post as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

`Find()` function returns first occurrence of matching item from the Collection which will be a single item that matched the condition. Since your view is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<LifestyleGuide.Models.Run>`, it's expecting a collection of Run objects not a single object. 
You should modify your controller so that a collection (list) of Run objects are passed to the view. You could use `WHERE` clause like this :

```
public ActionResult Details(String id, DateTime date)
    {
        using (var db = new inspireEntities())
        {
            List<Run> run = db.Runs.Where(r=>r.Id==id && r=>r.Date==date);
            return View(run);
        }
    }
```

Good luck :).

Comment: I have tried this method with some minor changes to your code and it didn't work. One thing that struck me was that the run list was null, which means the where query was faulty. Does it matter that my User_ID is a foreign key? Or does it matter that my date is not formatted to be the same for both the database and my view? I have my doubts on the date format as after all, it is still a datetime object.

Comment: How about giving a try only with id and see if this returns something? If the Id part is working, you can workout for the date later on.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! I found out that the DateTime object stored in the db contains milliseconds while the query doesn't include that.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the problem! Each entry to the database has a DateTime object with milliseconds while the query doesn't. I did a work-around to remove the milliseconds from all entries and it works!